# How to display a string in php?

Tags: php, html

I cannot display using php, what am I doing wrong ?

I have this file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <?php
    echo "My first PHP script!";
  ?> 

  </body>
</html>
```

in a file called `test.html`.

When I open that file in my browser, there is nothing shown.

Where is my problem ?

Comment: change file extension to php

Comment: Do you have any PHP server running ?

Comment: As above, to run php in a webpage, you need a php enabled webserver running, and you need to access the page via the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file should be saved as a php-file.

Like:

```
index.php
```

Also you'll need a server to host the files on. You can do this locally with USB-Webserver, xampp etc.

Answer (score 0):

file Type change

```
 test.html
```

to

```
 test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro HTML don't run PHP code you have to save the file as .php and paste this code on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you